# Display name of foreign key column instead of its id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a match table whose structure is displayed here

[image]

in this table i have column teama, teamb which are a foreign key columns referenced to `team` table's `t_id`. Basically, what i want to do is that when i select all data from this table i want it to display the values in `teama`, and `teamb` instead of their `t_id`. Structure of Team table is here

[image]

Query which i am writing is below:

```
select * 
from teams,matches 
where 
    matches.team_a=teams.t_id 
    and matches.team_b=teams.t_id;
```

Comment: Please add the the tables data to your question, instead on posting them as pictures.

Comment: What output do you get with this query? And how it is different then the expectations?

Comment: @Jahanzaib Niazi did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  You need two `JOIN`s in fact:

```
select m.*, ta.t_name as name_a, tb.t_name as name_b 
from matches m left join
     teams ta
     on m.team_a = ta.t_id left join
     teams tb
     on m.team_b = tb.t_id;
```

This uses `left join` just to ensure that you get all matches, even if one of the teams is missing.  In this case, that is probably not an important consideration, so `inner join` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join 2 columns of `matches` to the `teams` table:

```
select 
  m.m_id, 
  t1.t_name as team_a, 
  t2.t_name as team_b, 
  m.m_time
from 
  matches m inner join teams as t1 on m.team_a=t1.t_id
  inner join teams as t2 on m.team_b=t2.t_id
order by m.m_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want two INNER JOINs from table matches to table teams, like :

```
SELECT
    ta.t_name,
    tb.t_name
FROM
    matches m
    INNER JOIN team as ta on ta.t_id = matches.team_a
    INNER JOIN team as tb on tb.t_id = matches.team_b
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create view after join it was make your work simple for further developement,i was improove mr.forbas code as follow

```
CREATE VIEW team AS select 
m.m_id, 
t1.t_name as team_a, 
t2.t_name as team_b, 
m.m_time
 from 
matches m inner join teams as t1 on m.team_a=t1.t_id
inner join teams as t2 on m.team_b=t2.t_id
 order by m.m_id;
```

Comment: You did not bother to change even the aliases, just plain copy/paste.

Comment: I have improved your code only to the next step.you make a join so i mentioned after join in my above description.here i doesn't mention it is mine anywhere

Comment: You copied my code, added `CREATE VIEW team AS` at the beginning and pasted it as your code. Don't get used to it.

Comment: hey i agree that your code that's y i use after join k.